# Struts i18n app

Tags: struts, internationalization

Can anyone provide me sample code to develop a struts i18n application containing two `jsp` pages with two buttons (a single toggle button) to switch b/t two languages?

I am a new to struts.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need Struts to accomplish internationalization.  You can use the JSTL formatting tags.  You can use the fmt:bundle tag in your JSP to set the resource bundle to use.  Basically a resource bundle is a collection of property files, one for each language that your application supports, that have a common base name.  The fmt:message tag will print a message from the resource bundle based on a key.  The last thing you need to do is to use the fmt:setLocale tag to actually set the locale (in other words, which of the resource files in the bundle to use) based on what language you want to display.

A good place to start is here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL6.html

Answer (score 0):

You can start with [this link](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.7/userGuide/building_view.html) for some introductory info into internationalized messages then basically, for Struts i18n messages, you would use the [<bean:message>](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.7/userGuide/struts-bean.html#message) tag. The Action class has a [method](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/apidocs/org/apache/struts/action/Action.html#setLocale%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20java.util.Locale%29) you can use to set your desired locale in session scope and the message tags will pick it up from there.

There are plenty of examples you can find on the web (even if not as specific as you demanded :D). Maybe [this article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=101174) can get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Download sample app from [Struts site](http://struts.apache.org/download.cgi#struts2181) These sample application are packaged as WAR files. You can import HelloWorld.war from your eclipse and run index.jsp